# Поиск и замена элемента в xml документе

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Есть xml файл с множеством элеменотов. Строки выглядят так:

```
<note name="tossi" id="3" update="264" />
```

Как найти определенный `name` в документе и использовать его атрибут update в различных функциях?

То есть, нужен код: переменная `x=` значение атрибута `update` определенного элемента `name`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Я видел этот пример, но не смог применить его в своей задаче. Не совсем понимаю как составляется данная строка: nodeList=root.SelectNodes("descendant::book[author/last-name='Austen']"); Так же в примере нету атрибутов и идет выборка всех элементов, мне нужно один.

Comment: Я дал ссылку, чтобы Вы увидели слово "XPath". А дальше уже можно искать на "xml xpath selectnodes by attribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я бы сделал как-то так:

```
var id = 3;
var doc = XDocument.Load(...); // или XDocument.Parse(...)
var notes = doc.Descendants("note");
var note = notes.Where(n => (int?)n.Attribute("id") == 3).SingleOrDefault();
if (note == null)
{
    // нет такого элемента
}
else
{
    var update = (int)note.Attribute("update");
    // делайте дальше что хотите
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде то, что хотел, но у меня почему-то ошибка на этапе чтения из файла. Этот код дает ошибку                                                                                      XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml(filepath.Text);                                                                                        В то время как  XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(filepath.Text); проходит нормально.

Comment: @Юрий: Не-не, не `XmlDocument`, а `XDocument`. Это разные вещи.

Comment: Огромное спасибо=) несколько часов мучился, я не программист, но нужно было автоматизировать одну штуку. Еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @Юрий: Пожалуйста, надеюсь, что помогло.

Comment: @Юрий, если ответ решил вашу проблему - отметьте его как правильный.